# Post install script for autoscale in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I found a select box for post install scripts in adding auto scale group. Where can I register a new post install script to select ? Currently it always returns "None".

[image: postinstall script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the link in control portal 
https://control.softlayer.com/devices/scripts

using API this is the metod to fetch them:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPostProvisioningHooks

and here you can see the methods to create, delete, edit, etc:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook

Regards